Why isn't my new smart switch powering the lights?
The switch was previously just on/off to 4 can lights. I am trying to add smart dimmer to that one. The switch on the left controls 2 outdoor security camera w/flood lights.
Kasa smart wi-fi light switch HS220
The way it is wired here the switch is powered but lights won’t come on.  Extra white wire is coming from the power coming in to the box was never connected to previous regular switch.




did you follow the instructions

Yes I followed the directions.

Let's start with: Why are there two white wires just hanging out in the air?

Make/model # of new switch?

As always, it's a bit late but it would have been really helpful to have "before" pictures so we could see exactly what has been changed. Note that the smart switch probably requires a connection to neutral (to power it's own circuitry) that the ordinary switch didn't.

It seems that switch/circuit has hot, switched hot and neutral, so it should work.  Old style switch loops do not have neutral(but a hot white) which messes with smart switches.

switch the black and red on the switch and connect the white (neutral)

are you sure the can lights are dimmable?

@DIY75 - I believe you are correct. Red and black are reversed and the neutral needs to be connected.

after seeing your username being Not so handy, no replies from you on previous comments, and your statement of Extra white wire is coming from the power...  my comment contribution is to call an electrician... you kinda... don't know what you are doing.  Just posting a pic on the internet and then expecting to be able to now how to do electrical work (as simple as this should be) well.... did you turn the breaker back on after connecting this new switch?

Tried switching red and black wire there’s no power to the switch and light still won’t turn on.

I’ll call an electrician hope you guys got a laugh.  @ron thanks for your help

Based on the picture, the red and black wires have to switch positions.
Also, the smart switch needs the Neutral connected (the two white wires) to function.
